# Ignore an untracked file without changing .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

I want to ignore one specific untracked/new file without having to edit the .gitignore file for the repo. We'll call it `src/foo.xml`.

I have tried:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged src/foo.xml
git update-index --skip-worktree src/foo.xml
```

Both of which told me `Fatal: Unable to mark file src/foo.xml`, which I'm guessing is because it's not tracked in the first place.

I also tried adding `src/foo.xml` to .git/info/exclude. When that didn't work, I tried changing it to `/src/foo.xml`, then `C:/work/myproject/src/foo.xml`, neither of which worked.

In all cases, if I do `git status`, foo.xml still shows up as an untracked file to be added.

If I add `src/foo.xml` to the .gitignore file, it gets ignored as expected, but then I'm changing .gitignore which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Why not add it to the .gitignore ?

Comment: That's the point of the question. I *know* I can add it to .gitignore, but I'm looking for another way.

Comment: Sorry I will rephrase, Why do you wish to not use the exact reason .gitignore was made ?

Comment: Because .gitignore must be committed, and is not propagated to every existing branch. The file I need to ignore is used by an IDE plugin and varies by developer, rather than being part of the project and identical everywhere it (or a branch of it) is deployed. One could argue that the IDE plugin should put the file in some metadata outside the project, and I'd agree, but I can't very well modify a closed-source proprietary plugin to solve the original problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading though the comments. you want to ignore files but not commit the .gitignore

This is created by an IDE and will effect every project.

You dont want to commit but you do want to ignore.

Use the global git ignore

```
git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global
```

This file will be used for all projects commited to by your current user, without being part of any of them.